# Mysql transaction READ REPEATABLE and READ COMMITTED read view

Tags: mysql, transaction

I've come across something strage using Amazon RDS (MySQL 5.6.23).

I had issues when concurrent transactions were locking and then calculating a value from multiple tables. The following is a quick demo of what was happening when using transactions with isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`.

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Time | first transaction                             | second transaction                            |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1    | START TRANSACTION;                            | START TRANSACTION;                            |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 2    | SELECT * FROM stock WHERE sku=SKU0 FOR UPDATE | SELECT * FROM stock WHERE sku=SKU0 FOR UPDATE |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 3    | [GOT THE LOCK]                                | [WAIT]                                        |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 4    | SELECT s.qty - COUNT(r.fk_stock) AS qty       |                                               |
|      |   FROM stock s                                |                                               |
|      |   LEFT JOIN reservation r                     | [WAIT]                                        |
|      |   WHERE s.sku = SKU0                          |                                               |
|      |   GROUP BY s.simple_sku;                      |                                               |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 5    | qty === 10                                    |                                               |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 6    | INSERT INTO reservation ....                  | [WAIT]                                        |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 7    | SELECT s.qty - COUNT(r.fk_stock) AS qty       |                                               |
|      |   FROM stock s                                |                                               |
|      |   LEFT JOIN reservation r                     | [WAIT]                                        |
|      |   WHERE s.sku = SKU0                          |                                               |
|      |   GROUP BY s.simple_sku;                      |                                               |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 8    | qty === 9                                     |                                               |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 9    | UPDATE stock SET qty = 9                      |                                               |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 10   | COMMIT;                                       |                                               |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 11   |                                               | [GOT THE LOCK]                                |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 12   |                                               | SELECT s.qty - COUNT(r.fk_stock) AS qty       |
|      |                                               |   FROM stock s                                |
|      |                                               |   LEFT JOIN reservation r                     |
|      |                                               |   WHERE s.sku = SKU0                          |
|      |                                               |   GROUP BY s.simple_sku;                      |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 13   |                                               | qty === 10 <=== it should be 9                |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 14   |                                               | INSERT INTO reservation ....                  |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 15   |                                               | SELECT s.qty - COUNT(r.fk_stock) AS qty       |
|      |                                               |   FROM stock s                                |
|      |                                               |   LEFT JOIN reservation r                     |
|      |                                               |   WHERE s.sku = SKU0                          |
|      |                                               |   GROUP BY s.simple_sku;                      |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 16   |                                               | qty === 9 <=== it should be 8                 |
|      |                                               |                                               |
| 17   |                                               | UPDATE stock SET qty = 9                      |
|      |                                               |                                               |
|      |                                               | COMMIT;                                       |
|      |                                               |                                               |
|      |                                               |                                               |
+------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

As soon as I set isolation level to `READ COMMITTED` the problem is gone.

<strike>On my **local mysql** (MySQL 5.6.19) installation, I can do the same operation and I see the **right value** for `qty` using `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level.</strike> **Not true when using the same dataset that I have on RDS. See the answer below**

For what I found the [`REPEATABLE READ`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels/) isolation level creates a [`read view`](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysqlinnodb/entry/repeatable_read_isolation_level_in) at the beginning of first read and keeps reading values from that "view". The `READ COMMITTED` instead will create a `read view` for every read in a transaction, reading always the most fresher values.

<strike>This may explain ..., but I would expect to have the same behaviour also on my local mysql.</strike>

This explain what'a happening on RDS.

<strike>Has someone experienced something like this before?</strike>

Comment: I doubt if RDS is relevant.  Also, I suspect that all versions of InnoDB act the same.

Comment: @RickJames I would say the same, but I'm having two different results running the same transactions with isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`

Comment: @RickJames I've downloaded the whole data set I have on the RDS db and now even in local I have the same behaviour. I'll edit the question and write the an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to the amount of data present in the two tables.

In local I had a small part of the dataset I had on RDS. Once I've dumped the RDS data and load that in local I got the same bahaviour.

So, the flow seems to be:

1. after the first transaction `COMMIT`, mysql takes some time to update the table based on the number of its rows
2. This update comes after the second transaction starts its `SELECT s.qty - COUNT(r.fk_stock) AS qty ...`
3. So the second transaction reads from a `read view` created with the old data

To avoid this behaviour you need to use the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level. It seems that with this isolation level, the second transaction will wait the update of the table and then create a `read view`.